# cdef extern custom types in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I am using Cython to interface some C functionality with a Python application I am writing. I've practiced using Cython to call C code from Python before, with the code below demonstrating an example of what I normally do in `.pyx` files:

```
# wrapper.pyx

cdef extern from "customlib.h":
    int my_function(int value)

def call_c_code(value):
    output_value = engine(value)
    print(output_value)
```

...using my `customlib.h` file:

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_HEADER_H
#define CUSTOM_HEADER_H

/* function */
int my_function(int value);

#endif
```

...and then the corresponding Python implementation to call the function:

```
# caller.py

import wrapper

wrapper.call_c_code(5) # and then the result is printed... etc.
```

This works just fine. However, what if `my_function` is of a user-defined type, rather than `int`, `double`, etc.? The C code I am trying to interface with defines this struct

```
typedef struct 
{
    double *data;                 /* a 1D data array of type double */
    int nd;                       /* the number of dimensions */
    unsigned long *dimensions;    /* an array that contains the size of each dimension */
    unsigned long num_elem;       /* the number of elements in this array (cumprod(dimensions)) */
} dataArray_double;
```

and then defines functions with `dataArray_double` as both a return type and the types of some inputs.

What steps do I need to take to build my Cython interface code out to use functions with this custom type?

Answer (score 2):

You must create a container class that holds the C variable. A C variable (apart from numbers and characters) cannot be passed "as is" at the Python level. Look also for PyCapsule if you want a standard solution here.

In short, add the struct in the `cdef extern from "customlib.h":` part of your code and it will be available at the Cython level.